The instrument is not functional with android BLE writeCharacteristic
It's my first time posting questions, so if it's not enough, I'll post more.
I wrote the code writeCharacteristic using Java.
I get a return if I sent it normally, but there is no response from the device.
Map<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> desired = new LinkedHashMap<>();
desired.put("power", true);
desired.put("fan1", 3);

data.put("desired", desired);

JSONObject json = null;
json = new JSONObject(data);

String data2 = json.toString();

BluetoothGatt mBG = bluetoothGatt;
BluetoothGattService mSVC = bluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID.fromString(WriteServiceUUID));
BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCH = mSVC.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID.fromString(WriteCharacteristcUUID));
byte[] bytes;
try {
    bytes = data2.getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
mCH.setValue(bytes);
mBG.writeCharacteristic(mCH);

I want to know if I wrote something wrong or if the order is wrong.
enter image description here
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
Log.i("BLETEST", "onCharacteristicWrite");
try {
    Log.i("BLETEST", "characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid() + ", value: " + new String(characteristic.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + " status:" + status);
} catch (Exception e) { // UnsupportedEncodingException
    Log.i("BLETEST", "characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid() + " status:" + status);
}

The log came out like this.
Full code
package com.fakeeyes.bleTest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ble
    private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = null;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothDevice device = null;
    private BluetoothGattCallback callback = null;

    private BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = null;

    private List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicList = new ArrayList<>();

    // ui
    private Button btn_scan = null;
    private Button btn_size = null;
    private Button btn_state = null;
    private Button btn_service = null;

    Map<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });


        btn_scan = findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
        btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("BLETEST", "Starting scan");
                scanBluetoothDevices();
            }
        });

        btn_size = findViewById(R.id.btn_send_size);
        btn_size.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                String commmand = "{\"desired\":{\"power\":false}}";
//                String commmand = "{\"desired\":{\"power\":true,\"color\":\"warm\",\"fan1\":1,\"fan2\":0,\"fan3\":3}}";

                Map<String, Object> desired = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                desired.put("power", true);
//                desired.put("color", "warm");
//                desired.put("bright", 0);
                desired.put("fan1", 3);
//                desired.put("fan2", 1);
//                desired.put("fan3", 2);
//                desired.put("fan4", 3);

                data.put("desired", desired);

                JSONObject json = null;
                json = new JSONObject(data);

                int dataLength = data.toString().length();

                String data2 = json.toString();

                String size = Integer.toString(data2.length());

                Log.i("BLETEST", "size length:" + size);

//                Log.i("BLETEST", "command length:" + commmand.length());
//
//                String size = Integer.toString(commmand.length());

//                bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
//                bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(("ee3738d2-3b27-49aa-ab82-fcc624f7bd6c"), true);
//                bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(getCharacteristicStartWithUUID("01d6a875"), Integer.toString(dataLength).getBytes(), BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);

                BluetoothGatt mBG = bluetoothGatt;
                BluetoothGattService mSVC = bluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID.fromString("ee3738d2-3b27-49aa-ab82-fcc624f7bd6c"));
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCH = mSVC.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID.fromString("01d6a875-1594-4bc7-ba50-c80176a12b43"));
                byte[] bytes;
                try {
                    bytes = size.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                mCH.setValue(new String(bytes, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
//                mCH.setValue(abc);
                mBG.writeCharacteristic(mCH);
                boolean writeResult = mBG.writeCharacteristic(mCH);

                if (!writeResult)
                    mBG.discoverServices();

                Log.i("BLETEST", new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                Log.i("BLETEST", "sended size");
            }
        });

        btn_state = findViewById(R.id.btn_send_state);
        btn_state.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                String commmand = "{\"desired\":{\"power\":false}}";
//                String commmand = "{\"desired\":{\"power\":true,\"color\":\"warm\",\"fan1\":1,\"fan2\":0,\"fan3\":3}}";

                JSONObject json = null;
                json = new JSONObject(data);

                String data2 = json.toString();

                Log.i("BLETEST", "command:" + data2);

//                bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
//                bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(getCharacteristicStartWithUUID("9f61f774"), data.toString().getBytes(), BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);

                BluetoothGatt mBG = bluetoothGatt;
                BluetoothGattService mSVC = bluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID.fromString("ee3738d2-3b27-49aa-ab82-fcc624f7bd6c"));
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCH = mSVC.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID.fromString("9f61f774-d13c-4dd2-914f-d735925a68d3"));
                byte[] bytes;
                try {
                    bytes = data2.getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                mCH.setValue(new String(bytes, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                mCH.setValue(bytes);
                mBG.writeCharacteristic(mCH);

                Log.i("BLETEST", new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                Log.i("BLETEST", "sended state");
            }
        });

        btn_service = findViewById(R.id.btn_send_service);
        btn_service.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
//                bluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID.fromString("ee3738d2-3b27-49aa-ab82-fcc624f7bd6c"));

                Log.i("BLETEST", "sended service");
            }
        });
    }

    private byte[] stringToBytes(String str) {
        return str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }



    private void scanBluetoothDevices() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }

                BluetoothDevice _device = result.getDevice();

                String deviceName = _device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = _device.getAddress();

                if (deviceName != null) {
                    Log.i("BLETEST", "Device Name: " + deviceName + " Device Address: " + deviceAddress);

                    if (!deviceName.contains("LOUNGEBT")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    device = _device;

                    BluetoothGattCallback callback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

                            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "BLE Connecting...");
                            }
                            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "B LE Connected");
                                bluetoothGatt = gatt;
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "discoverServices: " + bluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "services Length: " + bluetoothGatt.getServices().size());
                            }
                            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING) {
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "BLE Disconnecting...");
                            }
                            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "BLE Disconnected");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCharacteristicChanged(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, @NonNull BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, @NonNull byte[] value) {
                            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic, value);
                            Log.i("BLETEST", "onCharacteristicChanged");
                        }

                        @SuppressLint({"MissingPermission", "NewApi"})
                        @Override
                        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                            Log.i("BLETEST", "onServicesDiscovered");
                            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
                            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                                List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                                for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
                                        Log.i("BLETEST", "[" + characteristic.getWriteType() + "] " + "serivice: " + service.getUuid() + ", uuid: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                                        characteristicList.add(characteristic);
                                    }
                                }

//                                BluetoothGattCharacteristic _characteristic1 = getCharacteristicStartWithUUID("c11f8635");
//                                gatt.readCharacteristic(_characteristic1);

//                                BluetoothGattCharacteristic _characteristic2 = getCharacteristicStartWithUUID("3a07886e");
//                                gatt.readCharacteristic(_characteristic2);

//                                BluetoothGattCharacteristic _characteristic3 = getCharacteristicStartWithUUID("14d68744");
//                                gatt.readCharacteristic(_characteristic3);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onServiceChanged(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt) {
                            super.onServiceChanged(gatt);
                            Log.i("BLETEST", "onServiceChanged");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
                            Log.i("BLETEST", "onCharacteristicWrite");
                            try {
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid() + ", value: " + new String(characteristic.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + " status:" + status);
                            } catch (Exception e) { // UnsupportedEncodingException
                                Log.i("BLETEST", "characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid() + " status:" + status);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCharacteristicRead(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, @NonNull BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, @NonNull byte[] value, int status) {
                            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, value, status);
                            Log.i("BLETEST", "onCharacteristicRead");
                            Log.i("BLETEST", "value: " + new String(value));
                        }


                    };

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        Log.i("BLETEST", "connectGatt... SDK_INT >= M");
                        device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, callback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_AUTO);
                    } else {
                        Log.i("BLETEST", "connectGatt...");
                        device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, callback);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                Log.i("BLETEST", "BLE Scan failed");
            }
        });
    }

    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic getCharacteristicStartWithUUID(String uuid) {
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicList) {
            if (characteristic.getUuid().toString().startsWith(uuid)) {
                return characteristic;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}


Your code snippet may look ok. However you haven't specified what is the peripheral device, does the characteristic you write support read, write and notify properties? You don't seem to set notify of the characteristic. Can you unveil all relevant code for bluetooth operations like instantiating bluetooth service, making connections etc.?

Peripherals are accepted normally.
read works normally.

It maybe a little hard to upload the entire code due to an error.

Oh friend, please delete that answer and post your code by editing your question. You can put your code at the bottom of your question by heading it with EDIT header.

Your code is very messy! Anyways, you said you did not get response when you write the characteristic. What kind of response you expect to get? Is it something like acknowledgement that indicates the value is written successfully or is it a response that you send from the firmware of peripheral device? Elaborate more please so that I can figure out the problem.

When you send a command, the device must perform the action.
It turns on when you enter the strength in fan1

Well, have you tested well your firmware of your peripheral device? What if the problem is at firmware end?

It didn't work because I had to split the command on Android.
